# Can a person get Jannahtul Firdaws by just reciting this after wudu, even if he doesn't do much good deeds?

Tags: hadith, hadith-interpretation, jannah, deeds

> It was narrated that Abu Hurayrah (may Allah be pleased with him)
> said: The Messenger of Allah (blessings and peace of Allah be upon
> him) said:  “Paradise is surrounded with difficulties and Hell is
> surrounded with desires.” Agreed upon.
>
> If Paradise is surrounded with difficulties and different kinds of
> hardships, then how about the highest of its degrees and the most
> sublime of its statuses?
>
> This indicates that the matter **is not something easy**.

Source: [Islamqa.info](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/135085/the-way-to-al-firdaws-al-ala)

So we know that Jannahtul Firdaws is the highest level of paradise. and it's not easy to get. people  who do less efforts can't get it.

but however

It was narrated that 'Umar bin Al-Khattab said:

> "The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said: 'Whoever performs Wudu' and does it
> well, then says: "Ashhadu an la ilaha ill-Allah was ashhadu anna
> Muhammadan 'abduhu wa rasuluh (I bear witness that there is none
> worthy of worship except Allah, and I bear witness that Muhammad is
> his slave and Messenger)," eight gates of Paradise will be opened for
> him, and he may enter through whichever one he wishes.'"

Sunan an-Nasa'i
English : Vol. 1, Book 1, Hadith 148

in this hadith it says if you just do wudu and recite "Ashhadu an la ilaha ill-Allah was ashhadu anna Muhammadan 'abduhu wa rasuluh" then you will get all the gets of paradise. **so if a person do less deeds or doesn't do other optional good deeds like sunnah prayer etc, and just recite that after wudu will he still get Jannahtul Firdaws? doesn't that makes it easy to get?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hadith of wudhu does not indicate that the person will be able to go to Jannat-al-Firdaws only for that action.

Rather the Prophet (SAW) says:

> فُتِّحَتْ لَهُ ثَمَانِيَةُ أَبْوَابِ الْجَنَّةِ
>
> All eight gates of Paradise will be opened for him.

The gates of Paradise do not correspond to the levels of Paradise. Meaning, it isn't like one gate will lead to Jannat-al-Firdaws. Rather the gates seem to be general entrances to Paradise and are something to honor worshipers in special ways. For example, those who fast a lot get a special gate.

There is plenty of proof that gates don't correspond to levels. For instance, there are exactly eight gates of Paradise as supported in other ahadith as well (see [here](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/59/67)). But, more than hundreds of levels paradise exist (see [here](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/56/8)). On that basis alone, it cannot be that gates correspond to levels.

In addition, the Prophet (SAW) says in this hadith: "يَدْخُلُ مِنْ أَيِّهَا شَاءَ " ("He may enter through whichever one he wishes") about the gates. If one gate automatically led to Jannat-al-Firdaws, the highest level, then why would there even be a choice? Who would choose something less?

Thus, it is clear the gates do not correspond necessarily to levels. Rather they are special honors which Allah gives.

Thus, in this hadith, the Prophet (SAW) is simply saying that the one who does wudhu in this manner (in addition to the reward of it) will get the honor of all gates opening for him.

Answer (score 2):

"@Yusha" السلام عليك

based on the hadith you mentioned about reciting after wudu and asking the following:

> so if a person do less deeds or doesn't do other optional good deeds
> like sunnah prayer etc, and just recite that after wudu will he still
> get Jannahtul Firdaws? doesn't that makes it easy to get?

the hadith mentions gates of paradise not the **firdaws**.

and for the interest to win it is by following what الله said about who is for it and what prophet محمد ﷺ recommended:

**[quran](http://quran.ksu.edu.sa/translations/english/304.html?a=2247)**:

saying of الله the most high:

> إِنَّ الَّذِينَ آمَنُوا وَعَمِلُوا الصَّالِحَاتِ كَانَتْ لَهُمْ
> جَنَّاتُ الْفِرْدَوْسِ نُزُلًا (107)
>
> (107 al-Kahf) Indeed, those who have believed and done righteous deeds - they
> will have the Gardens of Paradise as a lodging,

****[hadith](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/97/51)****:

the prophet محمد ﷺ said:

> so if you ask Allah for anything, ask Him for the Firdaus, for it is
> the last part of Paradise and the highest part of Paradise, and at its
> top there is the Throne of Beneficent, and from it gush forth the
> rivers of Paradise."

*I found an issue on the site's hadith*:

> middle of paradise not last part

Answer (score -1):

> Can a person get Jannahtul Firdaws by just reciting this after wudu,
> even if he doesn't do much good deeds?

As much as I know, I don't think so; since the deed(s) of human is a sort of necessary complementary for it -- and other similar issues.

Comment: It would be nice if you explained it in a more detailed way

Comment: @Yusha Confession must be proven in practice. أَحَسِبَ النَّاسُ أَنْ يُتْرَكُوا أَنْ يَقُولُوا آمَنَّا وَهُمْ لَا يُفْتَنُونَ ﴿۲  al-ankaboot (2).  "Do people think that they are left alone by saying: 'We are believers, ' and will not be tried?"

Comment: Dear Yusha, I'll do it later (if was free to do so).